# How to declare an array of pointers to int arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to declare an array of pointers each of which points to int arrays of different sizes. Any ideas?

Comment: Uhm, `int **myarray`?...

Comment: Use `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you are looking for a pointer to a pointer.

```
int **aofa;
aofa = malloc(sizeof(int*) * NUM_ARRAYS);
for (int i = 0 ; i != NUM_ARRAYS ; i++) {
    aofa[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * getNumItemsInArray(i));
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != NUM_ARRAYS ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j != getNumItemsInArray(i) ; j++) {
        aofa[i][j] = i + j;
    }
}
```

`NUM_ARRAYS` arrays may have different number of elements, as determined by the value returned by the `getNumItemsInArray(i)` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
int* ar[2];
int ar1[] = {1,2, 3};
int ar2[] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ar[0] = ar1;
ar[1] = ar2;
cout << ar[1][2];
```

Answer (score 2):

C version, should help clarifying the different types of declarations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
/* let's make the arrays first                                             */
int array_A[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int array_B[3] = {4, 5, 6};
int array_C[3] = {7, 8, 9};

/* now let's declare some pointers to such arrays:                          */
int (*pA)[3] = &array_A;
int (*pB)[3] = &array_B;
int (*pC)[3] = &array_C;  /* notice the difference:                         */
/* int *pA[3] would be an array of 3 pointers to int because the [] operator*/
/* has a higher precedence than *(pointer) operator. so the statement would */
/* read: array_of_3 elements of type_pointer_to_int                         */
/* BUT, "int (*pA)[3]" is read: pointer_A (points to) type_array_of_3_ints! */

/* so now we need a different array to hold these pointers:                 */
/* this is called an_ARRAY_of_3_pointers to_type_array_of_3_ints            */
int (*ARRAY[3])[3] = {pA, pB, pC};

/* along with a a double pointer to type_array_of_3_ints:                   */
int (**PTR)[3] = ARRAY;

/* and check that PTR now points to the first element of ARRAY:             */
if (*PTR == pA) printf("PTR points to the first pointer from ARRAY \n");

PTR++;

if (*PTR == pB) printf("PTR points to the second pointer from ARRAY! YAY!\n");

   return 0;
}

> $ clang prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu89 "-ansi"  output:   
> PTR points to the first pointer from ARRAY 
> PTR points to the second pointer from ARRAY! YAY!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section "Pointers to Arrays of Objects"
http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson24.htm
It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can declare it like shown below.new operator can work like similar to malloc in C.

```
int** array = new int*[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define arraySize 3

const int arr1[] = {48,49,50};
const int arr2[] = {64,65,66};
const int arr3[] = {67,68,69};

typedef const int (*arrayByte);

arrayByte arrayPointer[arraySize] = {
    arr1,arr2,arr3
};

void printArr(const int arr[], int size){
    for(uint8_t x=0;x<size;x++){
        printf("value%d=%d \n",x,arr[x]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    printf("Print Array 0\n");
    printArr(arrayPointer[0],arraySize);
    printf("Print Array 1\n");
    printArr(arrayPointer[1],arraySize);
    printf("Print Array 2\n");
    printArr(arrayPointer[2],arraySize);

    return 0;
}
```

try this code: [C++ online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler#)